# Examples of theories where tactic language is required for simple proofs

Tags: lean, agda, proof-assistant, tactic, proof-techniques

I was always under the impression, that separate tactic languages were generally considered to be vital for writing long proofs. I see tactic languages as a kind of interpreted DSL to generate boilerplate code while having much fewer static guarantees and much harder interactive stepping. This looks to me like a clear code smell, but I always assumed that is inevitable evil.

I solved most of [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/) Volume 1 (and partially 2) and while doing it, I spent most of my time trying to understand how tactic language works, not actually grasping PL theory or formal verification overall. After that, I found out that the Agda "variant" of SF [exists](https://plfa.github.io/), and I do not have any such issues with it. Almost all proofs seem clear to me at first sight, at least once you understand Agda syntax and the math idea behind proof. PLFA [case report](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167642320300502) claims that it was not clear that using language without tactics would not make things much longer, but in fact it worked very well. While PLFA is only covering part of SF, so far I do not see any reasons why the same reasoning would not work for the rest of SF.

I was looking and asking for examples of tactic usage in practice, where working without them would be painful, but did not find anything that would convince me. All examples I could understand seem to me either like tactic languages used as boilerplate generating (instead of design making proper proof reuse easy) or just using auto/ring/simp, which may work without any tactic language. I only understand PL theory and basic abstract algebra/topology well and also do not understand complex tactic code, which may be a reason I did not find suitable examples.

I know that SSReflect was used for proving multiple very complex results, but as far as I understand what is going on (not being able to get how this proof works in detail), it seems like the "reflect pattern" part of SSReflect is much more important for writing such kind of proofs, then is tactic language by itself.

So my current hypothesis is that any use of tactic language is possible to be refactored by using proof patterns/instrumentation which is possible (while not always actually implemented) in Agda-style language. By such I mean:

1. Boolean reflection [proof pattern](https://plfa.github.io/Decidable/#proof-by-reflection)
2. Libraries designed for proper code reuse by means of class types/parameterized modules/polymorphism
3. Interactive programming with case splitting and *auto* tooling (which is AFAIU is not SoA in Agda currently)
4. Large-scale decision procedures, like `ring`/`omega` tactics and external ATP integrations

So to (dis-)proof this hypothesis, I am asking for specific, clear, and (hopefully) short examples of theorems/theories/libraries for which proofs are simple/clear/nice with tactic language, but they would not be without them (even by using tools I listed before instead).

I would stress, that while the question may have some flame potential, I think that my question is clear and examples I am looking for may be very useful for discussion of proof techniques. So even if you do not agree with me, the question is clear and useful, so please do not vote for closing.

Partially related question:

- [What's the difference between reflection and tactics?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/whats-the-difference-between-reflection-and-tactics)

**UPD:**

I would like to reiterate, that I am asking for more specific examples not to confront anyone, and even not necessarily because I disagree. I just think that while general direction answers make sense as well, in such kinds of questions one must specify a specific task, a specific measure of "simple proof" and an overall goal, otherwise, the discussion is too vague and prone to "dynamic typing is bad" kind of holy war. Depending on proof/coding style and task people could evaluate measures of proof/code construction usability very differently.

Comment: Good question! Is there a typo in the title? It looks a bit confusing and ungrammatical as it is currently written.

Comment: Thanks. Linted with Gramarly, there was a *lot* grammar errors, hopefully it is better now.

Comment: Todays youth, they say things like "AFAIU" and "SoA".

Comment: A typo? "So do (dis-)proof this hypothesis" should be "So to (dis-)proof this hypothesis"?

Answer (score 4):

### so far I do not see any reasons why the same reasoning would not work for the rest of SF

Wait for (or jump straight to) at least https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/slf-current/Rules.html ;)

### 3. Interactive programming with case splitting and *auto* tooling

For one, I don't see why `auto` is not a tactic, or why it is an "acceptable tactic" in contrast to the rest. For sure I don't want `auto` in the *core* of my proof assistant! :D

Second, we're talking about proof *readability* and *understandability*. Long ladders of trivial case splits and straightforward proofs via substitution of the right equals for equals, or even induction are not very readable for me at all. To me, it's much more understandable when you swipe boring proofs under the rug of tactics and only keep the high-level structure of the argument before my eyes.

### 4. Large-scale decision procedures, like `ring`/`omega` tactics and external ATP integrations

I don't see the difference between "decision procedures" and "tactics"...

Moreover, we don't trust external tools, so we have to convert these external proofs from ATPs into our internal proofs for the proof assistant to double-check. And before that, we need to convert our goal and theorems from the internal format to the format of an external ATP. So we're taking the goal and theorems, processing them somehow, and spitting out a proof term. Congratulations, you've invented tactics! :D

Comment: > ... at least https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/slf-current/Rules.html

Could you please elaborate, on what you mean? You say that embedded non-classical logics, like separation logic, are hard to reason about in Agda? Could you give some specific reasons you have in mind?

Comment: I see them less acceptable because:

1. I am against "tactic languages", which are a strange kind of automation combination language, not any automation by itself. Decision procedures are self-contained, you just discharge them, and then you think the proof is only technical.
2. Auto as instrumentation gives you the resulting proof, which may be more direct to read (as a text, without interactive stepping).
3. Also, if tactic combination is really that essential, you I believe you could encode both normal forms and tactics inside language (`HDec` monad is an example).

Comment: > Long ladders of trivial case splits and 

Could you point me to any specific proof example, that you believe cannot be refactored in some well-readable form?

Comment: @uhbif19 "Could you please elaborate, on what you mean?" I think the burden of proof is on you now. :) Tactics in Volume 6 specifically made for Separation logic hide long and tedious proofs. I suggest you start by rewriting the same proofs without tactics at all and then show a better formalization that supports shorter and simpler proofs without tactics.

Comment: @uhbif19 "Could you point me to any specific proof example, that you believe cannot be refactored in some well-readable form?" You haven't provided an example of a proof that *can be*. ;)

Comment: @uhbif19 "I am against "tactic languages", which are a strange kind of automation combination language" People write tactics in all sorts of languages starting with ML itself (continuing with SML and OCaml nowadays), and lately in the host language with Elaborator reflection (Idris 1 and 2, Lean 4). So your objection makes little sense to me.

Comment: You state `\exists proof_x from SF_volume_6, such that  proof_x would be hard to rewrite in Agda`. As the game semantic of FOL prescribes, it is up to the Verifier to propose a value for the existing quantifier. As for an example of proof rewritable to Agda, one from SF 3 was already demonstrated to you in chat outside SO, I believe.

Comment: "People write tactics in all sorts of languages ..."

That does not take away any sort of objections people usually have for metaprogramming. One most relevant to the discussion is that of typed-vs-untyped quasi-quotation, typed one is better and almost nonexistent in practice. Writing proof generators in ML is a clear example of the untyped case: while ML has static types, they do not respect types in generated proof.

Comment: @uhbif19 please take a look at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-51054-1_10

Comment: OK, if you think you can rewrite any proof in Agda _simpler_ and _more concise_, here's one for you to play with: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/slf-current/Struct.html#Realization.ArrayAccessDef.triple_array_get :)

Comment: I am not looking for anything to "play with", I am looking for specific examples that you claim are impossible to rewrite without tactics complicating everything. Separation logic does not seem to have any reasons to be more complex to live without tactics.

Comment: You say you want examples, but you don't want to "play with" when you're given an example... Well, your claim any proof can be written more simply without tactics does not seem to have any reasons to be true. :)

Comment: It does have obvious reason. Boilerplate generation is code smell usually hiding incorrect design. Correct abstractions and refactored should not require constant code generation. I observed it in all examples I could understand. Most obvious are: blindly generating cases to solve, not using boolean reflection, not encoding properties within  datatype leading for long external proofs (with numbers and SMT for example) and regular code design problems (like not separating interfaces).

Comment: I believe that any PL design decision must be based on number of specific examples. That is how "enhancement proposals" work in big PLs. So I except that if that important feature framing theory proves landscape can be elaborated by specific examples by people who understand that. For example, I program Haskell, so I can show you specific examples why type classes (and also their sub-cases as interfaces  and traits) are important. Why not having them (or alternative) leads to worse abstractions. I can not give you "something to play with", but provide specific statement I believe is correct.